# mongoDB monggose partly update an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this model.
**User.js**

```
 methods: {
      type: [String],
      required: true,
    },
local: {
      email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
      },
      id: Number,
      title: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Ms', 'Mrs', 'Mr', 'Dr'],
        default: 'Mr',
      },
      firstName: String,
      lastName: String,
      role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user',
      },
      permissions: [String],
    },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
```

Please note that local field has many properties.
Say I only want to update few properties. namely title,lastName and role.

```
{
lastName:'virat',
role:'manager',
title:'Mr'
}
```

I tried to update it like this

```
const filter = { _id: req.params.id };
    const update = {
      local: {
        lastName: "virat",
        role: "manager",
        title: "Mr",
      },
    };

    await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

After the update, local has only 3 fields and other fields have been gone.
How do I update certain fields without losing the other fields?

Any help!
Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const filter = { _id: req.params.id };
const update = {
  "local.lastName": "virat",
  "local.role": "manager",
  "local.title": "Mr"
};

await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user
    .updateMany(
      { "local.id": id },
      {
        $set: {
          "local.$.title": title,
          "local.$.role": role, 
          "local.$.lastName":lastName
        },
      },
      {
        new: true,
      }
    ).then((update)=>{ response}).catch((err)=>{ err-response})
```

I hope you'll understand the response thing